# CPU Usage - Mysterious Query Running by root

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-sql

In the last two days I'd noticed that my Cloud SQL MYSQL CPU instance is higher than normal, even on idle time.

[image: Image - CPU usage graph]

When I execute the command `show full processlist;`, it shows a process of a query executed by "root" on "localhost" with the state "sending data".

The query is the follow:

```
SELECT 
    t.TABLE_SCHEMA AS TableSchema, t.TABLE_NAME AS TableName
    , t.TABLE_TYPE AS TableType, t.TABLE_COMMENT AS TableDescription
    , c.COLUMN_NAME AS ColumnName, c.COLUMN_COMMENT AS ColumnDescription
    , c.DATA_TYPE AS ColumnDataType, c.IS_NULLABLE AS ColumnIsNullable 
FROM information_schema.columns c JOIN information_schema.tables t ON(t.TABLE_NAME = c.TABLE_NAME AND t.TABLE_SCHEMA = c.TABLE_SCHEMA)
 WHERE t.TABLE_SCHEMA IN ('app_015861', more 14 databases of my instance..) 
  AND t.TABLE_NAME IN ('estoque_mov','caixa', all the tables of my databases..) 
ORDER BY TableSchema DESC, TableName DESC;
```

This query isn't from my application. It seems to be scanning all the tables of all databases of my instance.

All the times that CPU usage is back to normal levels this process isn't running.

Is this a process trigged by Google Cloud? If so, how can I stop it?

I'm using CloudSQL for more than 5 years and had never seem that.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a programming question per se. Perhaps [dba.se] would be a better place to ask.

Comment: I got this place on [Google Cloud documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/getting-support?hl=pt-br), but I'll ask there.
Thank you @TangentiallyPerpendicular.